Rotate container using the rotate container in flutter
I have one resizable container. When drag the rotate icon rotate container with the all resizable point update and the rotate icon position also change with rotation.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Movable Image Box'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MovableImageBox(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MovableImageBox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MovableTextBoxState createState() => _MovableTextBoxState();
  }


const ballDiameter = 15.0;
const rotateIconSize = 30.0;

class _MovableTextBoxState extends State<MovableImageBox> {
  double width = 150;
  double height = 100;
  double aspectRatio = 100/150;
  bool _isSelected = true;
  double top = 100;
  double left = 100;
  double rotationAngle = 0.0; // Initialize rotation angle
  Offset? startRotationPosition;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [

      Positioned(
        top: top,
        left: left,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _isSelected = true;
            });
          },
          onPanDown: (details) {
            setState(() {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
              _isSelected = true;
            });
          },
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            setState(() {
              top += details.delta.dy;
              left += details.delta.dx;
            });
          },

            child: Container(
              height: height,
              width: width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              decoration:
              BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 2,
                  color: _isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

      // Rotate Icon
      Positioned(
        top: top - rotateIconSize / 2 -30,
        left: left + width / 2 - rotateIconSize / 2,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onPanStart: (details) {
            startRotationPosition = details.localPosition;
          },
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            // ....
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.rotate_right,
            size: rotateIconSize,
          ),
        ),
      ),


      // top left
      if (_isSelected)
        Positioned(
          top: top - ballDiameter /2 ,
          left: left - ballDiameter /2,
          child: ManipulatingBall(
            onDrag: (dx, dy) {
              var newWidth = width - dx;
              var newHeight = newWidth * aspectRatio ;
              setState(() {
                if (newHeight > 10 && newWidth > 10) {
                  top = top + (height - newHeight) ;
                  left = left + dx;
                  height = newHeight;
                  width = newWidth;
                }
              });
            },
            handlerWidget: HandlerWidget.VERTICAL,
          ),
        ),
      //top mid
      if (_isSelected && (width > 10 && height > 10))
        Positioned(
          top: top - ballDiameter / 2,
          left: left + width / 2 - ballDiameter / 2,
          child: ManipulatingBall(
            onDrag: (dx, dy) {
              var newHeight = height - dy ;
              var newTop = top + dy;
              setState(() {
                if (newHeight > 10 && newTop >= 0 ) {
                  height = newHeight;
                  top = newTop;
                }
              });
              // cropImage(0, dy);
            },
            handlerWidget: HandlerWidget.HORIZONTAL,
          ),
        ),
      // top right
      if (_isSelected && (width > 10 && height > 10))
        Positioned(
          top: top - ballDiameter / 2,
          left: left + width - ballDiameter / 2,
          child: ManipulatingBall(
            onDrag: (dx, dy) {
              var newWidth = width +  dx;
              var newHeight = newWidth * aspectRatio ;
              setState(() {
                if (newHeight > 10 && newWidth > 10) {
                  top = top + (height - newHeight);
                  height = newHeight;
                  width = newWidth;
                }
              });
            },
            handlerWidget: HandlerWidget.VERTICAL,
          ),
        ),
      //bottom right
      if (_isSelected && (width > 10 && height > 10))
        Positioned(
          top: top + height - ballDiameter / 2,
          left: left + width - ballDiameter / 2,
          child: ManipulatingBall(
            onDrag: (dx, dy) {
              var newWidth = width +  dx;
              var newHeight = newWidth * aspectRatio ;
              setState(() {
                // isCorner = true;
                if (newHeight > 10 && newWidth > 10) {
                  height = newHeight;
                  width = newWidth;
                }
              });
            },
            handlerWidget: HandlerWidget.VERTICAL,
          ),
        ),
      //bottom left
      if (_isSelected && (width > 10 && height > 10))
        Positioned(
          top: top + height - ballDiameter / 2,
          left: left - ballDiameter / 2,
          child: ManipulatingBall(
            onDrag: (dx, dy) {
              var newWidth = width -  dx;
              var newHeight = newWidth * aspectRatio ;
              setState(() {
                if (newHeight > 10 && newWidth > 10) {
                  height = newHeight;
                  width = newWidth;
                  top = top + (height - newHeight) ;
                  left = left + dx;
                }
              });
            },
            handlerWidget: HandlerWidget.VERTICAL,
          ),
        ),
      //bottom mid
      if (_isSelected && (width > 10 && height > 10))
        Positioned(
          top: top + height - ballDiameter/2,
          left: left + width /2 - ballDiameter / 2,
          child: ManipulatingBall(
            onDrag: (dx, dy) {
              var newHeight = height + dy;
              setState(() {
                if (newHeight > 10 ) {
                  height = newHeight;
                }
              });
            },
            handlerWidget: HandlerWidget.HORIZONTAL,
          ),
        ),
    ]);
  }

}

class ManipulatingBall extends StatefulWidget {
  ManipulatingBall(
      {Key? key, required this.onDrag, required this.handlerWidget});

  final Function onDrag;
  final HandlerWidget handlerWidget;

  @override
  _ManipulatingBallState createState() => _ManipulatingBallState();
}

enum HandlerWidget { HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL }

class _ManipulatingBallState extends State<ManipulatingBall> {
  late double initX;
  late double initY;

  _handleDrag(details) {
    setState(() {
      initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
      initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
    });
  }

  _handleUpdate(details) {
    var dx = details.globalPosition.dx - initX;
    var dy = details.globalPosition.dy - initY;
    initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
    initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
    widget.onDrag(dx, dy);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanStart: _handleDrag,
      onPanUpdate: _handleUpdate,
      child: Container(
        width: ballDiameter,
        height: ballDiameter,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          shape: this.widget.handlerWidget == HandlerWidget.VERTICAL
              ? BoxShape.circle
              : BoxShape.rectangle,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I have one resizable container. When drag the rotate icon rotate container with the all resizable point update and the rotate icon position also change with rotation.
i have this type container

convert to this type of rotation

